# Problem with shuffle in Java (recurrence?)

Tags: java, reference

I writing Test Generator. In short, I've got 3 tests which I display on slide in PowerPoint presentation (1 question from all groups in different color for each slide). Of course there aren't two the same question in one slide. I want to mix displayed answers, because I don't want the same order of answers in the same question from others slides.
There is method for that:

```
private void shuffleAnswersInGroup(ArrayList<Question> group){
    for(Question question:group){
        String answerA = question.getAnswersContent().getAnswerA();
        String answerB = question.getAnswersContent().getAnswerB();
        String answerC = question.getAnswersContent().getAnswerC();
        String answerD = question.getAnswersContent().getAnswerD();
        AnswersContent answersContent = new AnswersContent(answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD);
        String questionType = question.getQuestionType();
        String answerCorrect = question.getAnswersCorrect();
        String correctAnswerContent = answersContent.getCorrectAnswerContent(answerCorrect);

        ArrayList<String> answersAsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(question.getAnswersAsArray(questionType));
        Collections.shuffle(answersAsArrayList);

        answersContent = setNewAnswerContentAfterMix(answersAsArrayList, answersContent);
        question.setAnswersContent(answersContent);
        int numberOfAnswerIsCorrect = numberOfCorrectAnswer(answersAsArrayList, correctAnswerContent);
        switch (numberOfAnswerIsCorrect) {
            case 0: {
                question.setAnswersCorrect("A");
            }
            break;
            case 1: {
                question.setAnswersCorrect("B");
            }
            break;
            case 2: {
                question.setAnswersCorrect("C");
            }
            break;
            case 3: {
                question.setAnswersCorrect("D");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I use that method for each of group and I've got the same answers order in responsive question from other groups. I think that my program use the same part of memory and that I get the same. How can I do that?

Comment: Just : to get the answer at the beginning, store the result of question.getAnswersContent() in a variable then use it :)

Comment: Looks like you need to copy the `Question` object - use a new copy for every slide that you use the question on. Otherwise, if you have only one question object, then the answer order is going to be the same everywhere that you use it.